# How do I back up and restore Passwords and Keys?

Tags: backup, keyrings, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I am installing Ubuntu on a new machine. How can I back up all the entries in *Passwords and Keys* (aka Seahorse aka GNOME Keyring), so I can transfer them to the new machine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Keyring data is stored in several places:

- "Passwords" (GNOME Keyring data) are stored in `~/.local/share/keyrings`
- "Secure Shell" data (SSH keys) are stored in `~/.ssh`
- "PGP Keys" (including GPG keys) are stored in `~/.gnupg`

  - Note that [copying the whole .gnupg folder copies your trust data as well](https://www.phildev.net/pgp/gpg_moving_keys.html), so this is probably preferable to doing an import/export through the "Passwords and Keys" interface.

You will need to backup and restore each of these folders. Preferably don't use a flash drive to do this (see note below). When restoring the folders, make sure the permissions are set correctly (see note below).

**Note on flash drives**

You should avoid using a flash drive to store/transfer keys, even temporarily, since deleted data is easily recoverable from a flash drive [unless you take precautions](https://www.howtogeek.com/187104/warning-anyone-can-recover-deleted-files-from-your-usb-drives-and-external-ssds/), like encrypting the drive. If you have a network connection, transfer over ssh would be both convenient and secure.

**Note on permissions**

When you restore the folders, they need the correct ownership permissions, which you can apply as follows:

```
chown --recursive USERNAME:USERNAME ~/.ssh
chmod 755 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# repeat the last two for other public/private pairs
# you may need to "service ssh restart" after changing these values

chown --recursive USERNAME:USERNAME ~/.gnupg
chmod 700 ~/.gnupg
chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*
# for any subfolders, you need to apply 700 to the folder
# and 600 to the files in that subfolder:
# chmod 700 ~/.gnupg/subfolder
# chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/subfolder/*
```

*References:*

- [Permissions on private key in .ssh folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/215504) (Super User)
- [Fixing “WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!” on GNU/Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/168119/fixing-warning-unprotected-private-key-file-on-linux/) (How-To Geek)
- [ssh returns "Bad owner or permissions on ~/.ssh/config"](https://serverfault.com/questions/253313) (Server Fault)
- [What are the correct permissions for the .gnupg enclosing folder? gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file](https://superuser.com/questions/954509) (Super User)
- [Notation of traditional Unix permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions), especially "Numeric notation" (Wikipedia)